# Parsing through DataTable for matching value and creating a new DataTable from the results

Tags: vb.net, datatables, duplicates

In VB.NET I'm trying to count through the value's in a list, until the value for "stock" in my DataTable, Boxes, is equal to the value in my list. When this occurs a row should be created in my new DataTable "output". I would then continue counting through the list looking for other matching instances to add into "output".

So far counting through the list and then within that count going through the datatable to match value's works wonderfully. The part where I'm getting hung up is when I try to take the matching row and put it into another table.

```
Dim output As DataTable
Dim jsonstringy As String = BoxComms.WebGet("http://foo.foo.foo")        'PULLS JSON STRING
Dim Boxes = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataTable)(jsonstring)
Dim MyString As String = TextBox1.Text               'MAKE STRING OF STOCK #'s FROM TEXTBOX
MyString = MyString.Replace(" ", "")                                     'GET RID OF SPACES
Dim MyArray() As String = MyString.Split(",")                'SEPERATE COMMA DELIMETED LIST
Dim MyList As List(Of String) = MyArray.ToList()

For Each value In MyList                                   'COUNT THROUGH LIST OF STOCK #'s
    For Each row As DataRow In Boxes.Rows
        If row("stock") = value Then      'IF STOCK # IS EQUAL TO ANY OF NUMBERS IN TEXTBOX
            output.ImportRow(row)         'ADD ROW FROM DATATABLE Boxes to DATATABLE output
        End If
    Next row
Next
```

Comment: A DataRow can only belong to one table.  There is probably a faster way to find the rows you want if you could explain further - you dont really "parse" datarows or datatables

Comment: I have a datatable being created from deserialized json stored in the cloud. there's a search function in my application. my application has a main DataGridView that gets used successfully for displaying various datatables my program is handeling. I'm trying to make a datatable to display the search results in my DataGridView. I've found various ways of copying datarow's from one table to another. I keep getting system.NullReferenceException's. I think I first need to copy my columns

Comment: If you could [edit] your post with some of that *and* some sample JSON, I'm pretty sure there is a faster, simpler way.  The problem is that we have no idea what any of that data looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was fairly simple, my DataTable needed a schema first. in order to copy the schema all I needed was to initialize the new table as a clone. to do so the code was as follows.

```
Dim output As DataTable = Boxes.Clone()
```

clone vs copy. copy get's the schema and data clone just gets the schema. then as I was parsing through the first table looking for matches I had to add the row to my new table with the following code.

```
output.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray)
```

the full code is as follows

```
        Dim jsonstring As String = BoxComms.WebGet("https://foo.foo.foo")
        Dim Boxes = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataTable)(jsonstring)
        Dim output As DataTable = Boxes.Clone()
        Dim MyString As String = TextBox1.Text
        MyString = MyString.Replace(" ", "")
        Dim MyArray() As String = MyString.Split(",")
        Dim MyList As List(Of String) = MyArray.ToList()
        For Each value In MyList
            For Each row As DataRow In Boxes.Rows
                If row("stock") = value Then
                    Console.WriteLine(row("stock"))
                    output.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray)
                End If
            Next row
        Next
        BoxControl.DataGridView1.DataSource = output
        Me.Close()
    End If
```